# Source for Chizzuk Gemara

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

Mori V'Rabi HaRav Schachter gave a speech at YU last week and in it said that there is a Gemarah that says that people who are learning Torah and are keeping Mitzvos also need Chizzuk. Where is this Gemarah?

Comment: Interesting that there would need to be a gemarah that says this. What is the _hava amina_?

Comment: I was wondering that also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Brachos 32b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=32b&format=pdf):

> The Rabbis taught in a *braisa*: Four things need Chizzuk, as follows: Torah, good deeds, prayer, and worldly affairs.
>
> From where do we know Torah and good deeds? As it says, "Just be strong (*chazzak*) and valiant (*v'ammatz*) to observe and perform according to the whole Torah ([Yehoshua 1:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15785#v=7))." "Be strong" in Torah, "and valiant" in good deeds.